# Extraordinarily Strange Behavior with Function triggering

Tags: javascript, node.js

Check this out. I've got a websockets nodejs app that has the following chunk of code:

```
socket.on('accelerometer', function (data) {
    console.log('*********');
    console.log(data);
    $(EVENTS).trigger('newAccelData', data);
});
```

`newAccelData` is bound to the function `processAccelData`, like so:

```
$(EVENTS).bind('newAccelData', processAccelData);
```

I'm not sure why it's written like that. I'm not familiar with Node, and this is based on someone else's code. Anyway, this is what `processAccelData` looks like:

```
function processAccelData(event, accel)
    {
        console.log('accel');
        console.log(accel);
        console.log("Accel Event: "+accel);

        $('#x').html(accel[0]);
        $('#y').html(accel[1]);
        $('#z').html(accel[2]);
    }
```

Okay, so here's where things get weird. In the `socket.on` code, when I log `data`, I get what I pass the socket elsewhere, an array of three strings, like this: `["1", "1", "2"]`. Okay, great. I then apparently pass this `data` object on to processAccelData with this line:

```
$(EVENTS).trigger('newAccelData', data);
```

Yet, when I reach `processAccelData` and I try to log the variable `accel`, I simply get `1`! If I change the array to have a different first number, I get that number, but no trace of the array. It somehow seems to be plucking the first number from my array without my permission. When I try to log the second and third indices, I get undefined! I'm completely baffled as to what is going on here.

Comment: I bet the array is being interpreted as an array of arguments instead of a single argument. Try adding console.log(arguments) and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(EVENTS).trigger('newAccelData', [data]);
```

The difference is that this way, data is the first argument in an array - and it won't itself (being an array) be interpreted as an args array.

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
.trigger( event [, extraParameters ] )
```

> **extraParameters Type: Array or PlainObject Additional parameters to pass along to the event handler.**